# Action Script 2 - gotoAndStop and if

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, var

I have a problem with my script, I want when a variable like "HP" is zero, then go to a specific frame.

```
if(_root.HP=0){gotoAndStop("34");}
```

Where `HP` = character life variable, and `34` = frame where is the target frame.

Comment: When you put something in quotes (eg: "thing"), you are telling the computer it is a `String` of text, not a number. Your code here says go to the frame with **label** name "34"... If you want a frame **number** use `gotoAndStop(34);`

Comment: yeah, i put it like you put,i just put the quotes for Decoration

Comment: Then it should work... What do you want help about? What is the error message you get? Does frame 34 exist?

Comment: Ah, the classics :) It should be if (_root.HP == 0)

Comment: thanks for help me,it worked.Hey,i need another help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45498744/how-could-i-begin-to-do-a-trading-card-game-in-flash-with-actionscript-2-0